# unable to connect emulator with internet

Tags: android-emulator

I am using Android 2.2 . I am unable to connect my emulator to internet .

When I open my web browser in the emulator it shows the message "Web Page not available" . I have set proxy settings in the emulator (settings -> Wireless & Networks ->Mobile Networks -> Access Point Names). Also , I set proxy settings in eclipse (Windows-> Preferences-> Android-> Launch-> Default Emulator Options). I have read many blogs and forums but I haven't found any solution yet .I am really frustrated .

Please help me out.

Abhijeet

Answer (score 2):

You have to start the emulator from the command prompt and supply the proxy server using something like this -

> emulator -avd MYAVD -http-proxy http://proxyname:8000

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and the best way is to do the following: This has been done for Android Emulator 2.2 1.Click on Menu 2.Click on Settings 3.Click on Wireless & Networks 4.Go to Mobile Networks 5.Go to Access Point Names 6.Here you will Telkila Internet, click on it. 7.In the Edit access point section, input the "proxy" and "port" 8.Also provide the Username and Password, rest of the fields leave them blank.